# Does this reaction that make an Alum happen?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, oxides

One day I asked a question in high school.
The problem is “Show the reaction that occurs when potassium permanganate is added to dilute sulfuric ferrous sulfateⅡ.

The answer is $\ce{2KMnO4 + 8H2SO4 + 10FeSO4
-> 2MnSO4 + 8H2O + 5Fe2(SO4)3 + K2SO4}$

I know this reaction because I have studied oxidation reaction.

But I have a question.

The reaction that  $$\ce{KMnO4 + 4H2O + 5FeSO4 + 8H2O -> MnSO4 + FeK(SO4)2・12H2O + 2Fe2(SO4)3}$$ (like a Alum) is happen?

The reason this question arose is that I can think of combinations that are alum when each becomes an ion after iron oxidizes.

Would you mind solving my question?

Comment: How can you distress a question? If we find out maybe we can scare off some of them ;)

Comment: More to the point, all products are dissolved. If you tried to crystallise some of the stuff, then we could talk.

Comment: Thanks to see my question.The textbook only written the upper  reaction equation and not written the equation that I think to produce alum(FeK(SO4)2) that I thought of.
I wondered if alum(FeK(SO4)2) can be made.

Comment: Yes, I know that all material is ion in water.
But in the reaction equation, wouldn't you write it without it being an ion?
For example, although Na+ Cl- in water, HCl+NaOH->NaCl+H2O in a neut.
I was thought that if there is an ion, it is a half-reactive equation.

Comment: BTW, alum is a specific example of a **double salt**, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_salt . Since no aluminum was involved, you might use the general term.

Comment: Thanks for looking DrMoishe Pippik.
My textbook said that anything that can be represented as M1M2SO4 is called alum.
And, the Double salt article on Wikipedia first says that alum can be represented by MIMIII(SO4)2-12H2O.
However, the alum article says it is a salt of aluminum, so it would have been better to write it as a double salt.
Thank you for correcting.

Comment: Also, I appreciate you DrMoishe Pippik for your help in correcting the reaction equation.

Comment: Thank Michael Lautman for the formula edit. As for *alum* vs. *double salt*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alum .

Comment: Your 2nd reaction is disbalanced, 5 sulfates on left, 9 on right.

Comment: sorry Poutnik, I mistakenly write 4H2O where 4H2SO4 was.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the above reactions do not happen in the presented molecular form, but in ionic form. Dissolved anions and cations are separated and independent (safe minor ion pair formation) until the solubility product of the least soluble salt is achieved. Then the respective ions mutually combine, eventually with crystal water and form the respective least soluble solid salt.

The oxidation reaction goes like this:

$$\ce{MnO4-(aq) + 5 Fe^2+(aq) + 8 H+(aq) -> Mn^2+(aq) + 5 Fe^3+(aq) + 4 H2O(l)}$$

The remaining ions $\ce{K+(aq)}$ and $\ce{SO4^2-(aq)}$ are bystanders not taking part in the above reaction. They are therefore not explicitly added to the reaction equation.

As the next step, e.g. via evaporation, there can happen eventual crystalization of respective salts, according to their solubility products:

\begin{align}
\ce{K+(aq) + Fe^3+(aq) + 2 SO4^2-(aq) + 12 H2O(l) &<=> KFe^{III}(SO4)2 . 12 H2O(s)}\\
\ce{2 K+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq) &<=> K2SO4(s)}\\
\ce{Mn^2+(aq) + SO4^2-(aq) + $n$ H2O(l) &<=> MnSO4(s) . $n$ H2O(s)}\\
\ce{2 Fe^3+(aq) + 3 SO4^2-(aq) + $n$ H2O(l) &<=> Fe2(SO4)3 . $n$ H2O(s)}
\end{align}

The [Wikipedia: Solubility table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table) can be used for respective salts as the guidance, but it is valid for pure salts with stoichiometric rations of respective ions. An excess of one of ions (aka common ion effect), e.g. sulfate from sulfuric acid, decreases the solubility of the affected salt.

Comment: What can be gleaned from the discussion is that the most efficacious method to effect a synthesis involves the simplest combination of reactants. To make FeK[SO4]2 the reaction with permanganate could be eliminated.  The complete "molecular" equation does not necessarily depict the actual products isolated.

Comment: @jimchmst But the task is not the simplest method to synthetize the alum, but to resolve outcome of the redox reaction, regarding possible isolation of products.

Comment: My second sentence. The reaction to give the mixed salt is suspect because permanganate requires an acidic reaction to be reduced to Mn++.  The second equation fails to describe a possible reality.

Comment: I have made no claim about the validity of his 2nd reaction, which is disbalanced.

Comment: Thanks to answer my question Poutnik.So, when each salt crystallizes, there are four possible reaction equations.I understand.

Comment: I assume, but not sure, that there could be formed also Mn equivalent of the Mohr salt, i.e. K2Mn(SO4)2. 6 H2O.